# Unbalanced Haar Wavelets and R package unbalhaar

Tags: r, wavelet

I have found the article by [Fryzlewicz  (2007)](http://stats.lse.ac.uk/fryzlewicz/uh/uh.pdf) and his R package [unbalhaar](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/unbalhaar/unbalhaar.pdf).

I do not understand well the outputs of his functions and in particular of the `best.unbal.haar.bu()` function. Here is the documentation of it : [best.unbal.haar.bu](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/unbalhaar/docs/best.unbal.haar.bu).

From his article, I have understood that the `$smooth` argument is the constant factor, and that `$detail[1,]` is the location of the coefficients and `$detail[3,]` is the value of the coefficients.

But I do not see what could be `$detail[2,]` called "weights" in the documentation...

Does anyone know about this work and know what it is ?

Thank you for your help.

PS : I have not posted this question on stackoverflow because I think it is more about the maths than about the coding thing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough about the work to give a complete answer, but the number in `detail[2,]` is one of the numbers denoted $a_{p,q}$ or $b_{q+1,r}$ on page 17 of the paper. I am not sure which, but you should be able to find out by working through an example.

To get this, you can look at the `reconstr.bu` function, which reconstructs the original signal from the output of the `best.unbal.haar.bu` function. Say that your signal is `x` and `y = best.unbal.haar.bu(x)`. Then the source code of `reconstr.bu` shows how `x` is recovered from `y$smooth` and `y$detail`

```
 function (buh.bu) 
        {
            y <- buh.bu
            n <- dim(y$detail)[2] + 1
                x <- y$smooth
            detail <- y$detail
            for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
                ind <- round(detail[1, n - i])
                x[(ind + 2):n] <- x[(ind + 1):(n - 1)]
                new.left <- detail[2, n - i] * x[ind] + sqrt(1 - detail[2, 
                    n - i]^2) * detail[3, n - i]
                new.right <- sqrt(1 - detail[2, n - i]^2) * x[ind] - 
                    detail[2, n - i] * detail[3, n - i]
                x[ind] <- new.left
                x[ind + 1] <- new.right
            }

        return(x)
    }
```

You can see where `detail[2, n - i]` enters into the code, and its clear that one of `detail[2, n - i]` and `sqrt(1 - detail[2, n - i]^2)` is $a_{p,q}$ and the other is $b_{q+1,r}$. Only one of them needs to be stored in `y` because the sum of their squares is $1$. (See 2(b) on p17 of the paper.) The columns of `y$detail` are the detail filters into which the signal `x` is broken. The signal can be completely recovered from this set of detail filters.

I hope this is of some help. I made it an answer because it's too long to be a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped mr but it is only a part of the answer I am searching for.